# Boost asio Error: Host not found (non-authoritative), try again later

Tags: c++, boost

i need this solution with c++. Example txt is here "www.asd.com/try.txt" i need read from txt. I have an error `Error: Host not found (non-authoritative), try again later`. What is my mistake? (website and path are true "asd" is just example)

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.connect("www.asd.com", "http");
    if (!stream)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << stream.error().message() << "\n";
    }
    stream << "GET /ip.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    stream << "Host: www.asd.com\r\n";
    stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
    stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    for (std::string line; getline(stream, line);)
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means the domain (or service) cannot be resolved to an endpoint.

That domain is `www.asd.com` here, and the service is `http`. Both resolve on my machine, but it depends on your host: e.g. in some settings (containers?) there might not be any DNS resolver configured.